# How do I add data to a Google Sheet from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-api

There's a [Ruby Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby) in Google's developers site, but it only demonstrates how to get data from a spreadsheet, not adding data to it.

Is there some easy example out there explaining how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's suppose you have an array of emails you want to add to a spreadsheet:

```
def generate_emails
  10.times.map { |i| ["email#{i}@example.com"] }
end
```

Now, after initializing the API (just after calling the `authorize` method), prepare the value range object with the data, and append it to the spreadsheet using the API:

```
# Adds the email addresses to the spreadsheet
value_range_object = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new(values: generate_emails)
response = service.append_spreadsheet_value(
           SPREADSHEET_ID,
           RANGE,
           value_range_object,
           value_input_option: VALUE_INPUT_OPTION)
```

Don't forget to define the `SPREADSHEET_ID`, and the other two constants:

```
RANGE = 'Sheet1!A1'
VALUE_INPUT_OPTION = 'RAW'
```

This will add your data to the existing content (it will not be overwritten).